# Twitter iOS Login Button using Storyboard?

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I've used Fabric to import `TwitterKit` into my Swift XCode project. I'm wanting to create the Twitter login button using a UIView, such that I can lay it out in the Storyboard.

Here's what I've done:

1) I've created a UIView in the Storyboard and set the class to `TWTRLogInButton`. [image: TWTRLogInButton Class]

2) In my view controller, I've created an IBOutlet.

```
@IBOutlet var twitterLoginView: TWTRLogInButton!
```

3) I've modified the sample code from Fabric to suit my setup. Here's the original code from Fabric that goes in my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
        let logInButton = TWTRLogInButton { (session, error) in
        if let unwrappedSession = session {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logged In",
                message: "User \(unwrappedSession.userName) has logged in",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
            )
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            NSLog("Login error: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
        }
    }

    // TODO: Change where the log in button is positioned in your view
    logInButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(logInButton)
```

Here's my edited code to reference my view instead:

```
twitterLoginView = TWTRLogInButton { (session, error) in
        if let unwrappedSession = session {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logged In",
                message: "User \(unwrappedSession.userName) has logged in",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
            )
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Login Error, \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

XCode accepts this, but when I launch the app, I get the following error in the logs when I select the Twitter Login Button:

> TWTRLogInButton was created with no completionBlock set

I'm not sure why this is happening, anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Where did you call twitterLoginView?

Comment: The part I labeled 'my edited code' was referenced in `viewDidLoad`. Fabric gives me some code to add in the viewDidLoad, and I have attempted modifying it slightly to fit the fact that I've already added the button on the Storyboard. Do I need to call it elsewhere?

Comment: You get your warning because you created your button as IBOutlet. You are trying to override your variable. If you create it programitacally you will get no error in this case.

Comment: So does it need to be an Action which will call this code instead? Or is there no way to do this via the Storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

`buttonWithLogInCompletion` is class method. You are creating your IBOutlet in your storyboard without calling the instance method. Overriding it gives that warning. Your code works by the way. If you don't want to see that warning you should create your button in your code programmatically as you wrote in your question:

```
    let logInButton = TWTRLogInButton { (session, error) in
    if let unwrappedSession = session {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logged In",
            message: "User \(unwrappedSession.userName) has logged in",
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
        )
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        NSLog("Login error: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
    }
}

// TODO: Change where the log in button is positioned in your view
logInButton.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(logInButton)
```

You can set the button position with autolayout in your code also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Guess it will be in code then! :) I've never done autolayout using code before, so will try it out now using this guide from the Apple Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html - I'll let you know how I get on! Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: I said in my answer. Your code works. Getting the warning does not mean that your code is wrong. Creating IBOutlet calls the basic init(). In your code  you are just overriding it.

Comment: So what I'm effectively doing by creating the IBOutlet is creating a new instance of the button. In the viewDidLoad, I'm overriding the completion block for that instance I created? Is that correct? Sorry for this, I think I'm viewing this from the wrong angle!

Comment: Yes, you are saying correct. IBOutlet creates the button without completion block. You are just overriding it.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that I'm not actually doing anything by overriding it? It seems that I'm not getting the 'user has logged in' message when I press the button either? Surely if I had overridden it correctly, it would work?

Comment: It should direct you to the settings if you did not activated it. You should see user has logged in if you have already logged in.

Comment: I can see this with the original code given to me by Fabric (although of course my button is incorrectly placed), but not using my modified code where I've overridden the created instance.

Comment: For anyone that views this thread in the future, I decided to go against using the default Twitter Login Button and made my own instead. They have some code on their site to do this. A huge thanks to ridvankucuk for the help! :)